# What schema should mark up comment that are in response to other comments?

Tags: microdata, comments, articles

I have an article that has user comments. I would like to have other comments inside each comment as responses:

```
<article id="com1" itemprop="comment" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/UserComments">
      <header>
                <h3>Posted by: <span itemprop="creator">Alexutu Mutu</span></h3>
      </header>

      <p itemprop="commentText">comment text here.....</p>

      <footer>
                <time itemprop="commentTime" datetime="...">...</time>
      </footer>
</article>
```

Comment: A response is a comment too. Also, you're bloating your code: There's no real reason why you should have to use header, footer or even article, you're making unnecessary lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reply to a comment is still classified a comment under the schema standard. Each comment and replies to those comments are still `itemprop="comment"`